# Save / Show multi line text in metabox

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, metabox

In a plugin I have made (Snup Widget) I have made a metabox.
In the sample here I have made two line with text.
When I want to show the text in output in the widget it shows in one line, without break.

If I write the text in two lines, and save the post.
The text have move into one line when I load / open the post editor again.

Why ?

[image]

```
/*
 * ---------------------------------- *
 * Add Custom Text Field 
 * ---------------------------------- *
 */

function snup_add_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box (
        'snup_id', //id
        'Show Next Upcoming Post', //title
        'snup_callback', //callback
        'post', //screen
        'normal', //context
        'default', //priority

    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'snup_add_meta_box');


function snup_callback($post){ 
    wp_nonce_field('snup_meta_box', 'snup_meta_box_nonce');

$snuptext = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'snuptext', true);
$label1=__('Please type the teaser text here','snup-lang');
$label2=__('Max 100 characters.', 'snup-lang');

?>
    <p>
    <label><b><?php echo esc_html_e($label1);?></b></label><br>
    <label><?php echo esc_html_e($label2);?></label><br>
    <textarea style="resize:none" name="snuptext" rows="3" cols="100%" maxlength="100"><?php echo esc_textarea($snuptext);?></textarea>
    </p>
    

<?php }


/*
 * ---------------------------------- *
 * Save Custom Text Field 
 * ---------------------------------- *
 */


function snup_save_meta($post_id) {

// Check if out nonce is set.

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['snup_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

// Verify that the nonce is valid.

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['snup_meta_box_nonce'], 'snup_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }


// Make sure that it(input) is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['snuptext'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    
    //Sanitize user input.
    $snuptext = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['snuptext'] );


    //Update the meta field in the databse.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'snuptext', $snuptext );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'snup_save_meta' );


/*
 * ---------------------------------- *
 * Show the info in SNUP
 * ---------------------------------- *
 */
function snupwidget_upcoming_posts() { 

    $output = '';

    // The query to fetch future posts
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 
        'post_status' => 'future',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ));
 

// The loop to display posts
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $output .='<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query-> the_post();
        $output .= ''. get_the_post_thumbnail() .' <div class="snup_title"> '. get_the_title() .' </div><div class="snup_text"> '. get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'snuptext', true ). ' </div><div class="snup_published"> '. __('Published', 'snup-lang') . '</div><div class="snup_time"> '.  get_the_time('d.m.Y H:i') .') </div>';
    endwhile;
    $output .='</ul>';

} else {
    // Show this when no future posts are found
    $output .= '<div class="snup_noplan"> '. __('No planed posts yet.', 'snup-lang') . '</div>';
}
// Reset post data
wp_reset_postdata();
 
// Return output
 
return $output; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why ?

You are using [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) in the metabox save function. According to the code referensece it,

> - Checks for invalid UTF-8,
> - Converts single < characters to entities
> - Strips all tags
> - **Removes line breaks**, tabs, and extra whitespace
> - Strips octets

When saving textarea you want to use [`sanitize_textarea_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_textarea_field/) instead.

> The function is like sanitize_text_field(), but **preserves new lines**
> (\n) and other whitespace, which are legitimate input in textarea
> elements.

**UPDATE**

For fixing the output, you could do something like this. The key part here is `str_replace()`, which is used to replace the different types of linebreaks with `<br>` tags. If you want to have `p` tags also, you could consider using [`wpautop()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/) instead.

*Please don't mind that I took the liberty to format the output handling a bit.*

```
if ( ! $the_query->posts ) {
  return sprintf(
    '<div class="snup_noplan">%s</div>',
    esc_html__('No planned posts yet.', 'snup-lang')
  );
}

$items = array();
foreach ($the_query->posts as $post) {

  $snuptext = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'snuptext', true );
  if ( $snuptext && is_string( $snuptext ) ) {
    // turn linebreaks to <br>
    // @source https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php#73440
    $snuptext = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $snuptext);
  } else {
    $snuptext = '';
  }
  
  $items[] = sprintf(
    '<li>
      %s
      <div class="snup_title">%s</div>
      <div class="snup_text">%s</div>
      <div class="snup_published">%s</div>
      <div class="snup_time">%s</div>
    </li>',
    get_the_post_thumbnail($post),
    esc_html( $post->post_title ),
    esc_html( $snuptext ),
    esc_html__('Published', 'snup-lang'),
    get_the_time('d.m.Y H:i', $post)
  );
}

return sprintf('<ul>%s</ul>', implode('', $items));
```

Comment: Thanks.... It works....
Now I change to textarea and I can write multi line, save / update and it still look the same... :) 

Now is the question how to get the multi line to show in the output in the widget.  
You can see the output code in my code example in this question.
Under the "Show the info in SNUP"

Comment: @bjovaar I updated my answer with a code example regarding the output handling. I think this should do the trick.

Comment: I try to change the code from ```// The loop to display posts```  that I have done, to the code you have posted.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in snup-widget.php on line 367

Here is the snup-plugin.php file with your code.
From line 320
[link](https://github.com/bjovaar/SNUP/tree/main/new-output)

Comment: @bjovaar I think you're missing the closing curly bracket for `snupwidget_upcoming_posts()` function. Check your `debug.log` to find out the exact reason.

Comment: That was correct.... I add closing curly bracket to close the function.

When I test the plugin now...
I can add multi line in the metabox, update / save.
When I go to the front side where the widget is.... its still at one long line.

https://ibb.co/YLhtpv8
https://ibb.co/NYGvkZM

Comment: @bjovaar You could try `var_dump()`ing the meta value right after getting it to see how it looks. It might be better to open another question to get the output problem sorted as the original question is to my understanding solved.