# How to show multi line output from metabox

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

In a plugin I have made (Snup Widget) I have made a metabox.
In the sample here I have made two line with text. When I want to show the text in output in the widget it shows in one line, without break.

If I write the text in two lines, and save the post.
The text is still in two lines when I load / open the post editor again.
The problem is that they show up in one line in the output, not in two line as in editor.

[image]

I have now edited some of the code, but the problem is still that the text show up in one long line in the output.

[image]

The file is here:
https://github.com/bjovaar/SNUP/tree/main/new-output

```
/*
 * ---------------------------------- *
 * Show the info in SNUP
 * ---------------------------------- *
 */
function snupwidget_upcoming_posts() { 

    $output = '';

    // The query to fetch future posts
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 
        'post_status' => 'future',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ));
 

// The loop to display posts
if ( ! $the_query->posts ) {
  return sprintf(
    '<div class="snup_noplan">%s</div>',
    esc_html__('No planned posts yet.', 'snup-lang')
  );
}

$items = array();
foreach ($the_query->posts as $post) {

  $snuptext = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'snuptext', true );
  if ( $snuptext && is_string( $snuptext ) ) {
    // turn linebreaks to <br>
    // @source https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php#73440
    $snuptext = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $snuptext);
  } else {
    $snuptext = '';
  }
  
  $items[] = sprintf(
    '<li>
      %s
      <div class="snup_title">%s</div>
      <div class="snup_text">%s</div>
      <div class="snup_published">%s</div>
      <div class="snup_time">%s</div>
    </li>',
    get_the_post_thumbnail($post),
    esc_html( $post->post_title ),
    esc_html( $snuptext ),
    esc_html__('Published', 'snup-lang'),
    get_the_time('d.m.Y H:i', $post)
  );
}

return sprintf('<ul>%s</ul>', implode('', $items));
}
 



// Add shortcode
add_shortcode('snup-widget', 'snupwidget_upcoming_posts'); 
// Enable shortcode execution inside text widgets
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a new look now at the `sprintf()` part of the example I shared in [my answer to your previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/403922/144392). The thing that might contribute to the rendering problem is the `esc_html( $snuptext )` line as it is basically disabling the `<br>` tags that are added with the `str_replace()` earlier. (*I'm so used to using `esc_html` that I'm almost blind to it.*)

So the `sprintf` would look like this,

```
$items[] = sprintf(
    '<li>
      %s
      <div class="snup_title">%s</div>
      <div class="snup_text">%s</div>
      <div class="snup_published">%s</div>
      <div class="snup_time">%s</div>
    </li>',
    get_the_post_thumbnail($post),
    esc_html( $post->post_title ),
    $snuptext,
    esc_html__('Published', 'snup-lang'),
    get_the_time('d.m.Y H:i', $post)
  );
```

I tested this locally in my sandbox WP and it seemed to work.

If you don't want to allow other html in the widget excerpt text, then you could do something like this when doing the `str_replace`.

```
$snuptext = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", strip_tags($snuptext));
```